# Error when calling local variable in GUI MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, image-processing, callback, matlab-guide

I'm getting this error:

```
Error in ==> APP>pushbutton2_Callback at 109
img=imread(FileName)
```

When I try to use `FileName` in `pushbutton2_Callback` I'm getting the error mentioned

`FileName` is variable in `pushbutton1_Callback`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the variable `FileName` from one callback to the other. To do this, you can assign the variable to the `'UserData'` field of `pushbutton1`. Your code under `pushbutton1_Callback` should look something like:

```
FileName=uigetfile();
set(handles.pushbutton1,'UserData',FileName);
```

Next, you need to read in the variable under your `pushbutton2_Callback`:

```
FileName=get(handles.pushbutton1,'UserData');
img=imread(FileName);
```

If you want to check your results, you can always leave the semicolons off the end of the lines.

Answer (score 1):

There's a general method to store data with your gui for use between callbacks.  You can add arbitrary fields to the handles object, so you can put in your pushbutton1 callback

```
handles.filename = FileName;
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

The second line is boilerplate code that you need to put at the end of any callback that changes values in the handles structure.

Now all of your callbacks will have access to the file name.  In your specific case, in callback 2, you would have

```
img = imread(handles.filename);
```

Of course, you might want to use this image later on in another function, so you can store it in handles too

```
handles.img = img;
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Comment: You can do effectively the same thing with setappdata and getappdata without having to remember the guidata bit.

Comment: But then you have to know the figure handle, right?  I guess you could call gcf, but then you'd run into a problem if the user maximized another window before your callback executed.  I prefer the dot reference notation anyway.